# router.changes.subscribe deprecated in angular2 router rc2

Tags: angular2-router3

It seems `router.changes.subscribe` is deprecated.

What can be used in place of this?

I want to do something on each router changes, so please provide me help what could be done as router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this solution.

```
router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
}
// NavigationEnd
// NavigationCancel
// NavigationError
// RoutesRecognized
```

}